# how to display background image above the inner div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I would like to display the background image above the inner div. How can I do this?

Here is a [code pen](https://codepen.io/aspnetgal/pen/VBJEvL), my code is shown below.

```css
.adv-signup {position: relative;  background: #ffffff url("https://s6.postimg.cc/ugw1p1pcx/sprite.png ") no-repeat left top;
  width: 1000px; height: 500px;}

 
.contents {position: absolute; background: blue; width: 800px; height: 200px;top: 20px; left: 30px; }
```

```html
<div class="adv-signup">
        <div class="contents">
            <div class="text">
                <h3>Sign up for E-News</h3>
                <p>Leave your email and we’ll send you regular updates on programs, events and news.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="controls">
                <input name="adv-sign-up-email-field" id="adv-sign-up-email-field" type="text" maxlength="255" value="Enter your email" />
                <a href="#" class="btn"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
<div>
```

Comment: if you have any other way pls let me know

Comment: You can't have a background-image show "above" content with a background-color. You could specify `z-index: -1` on `.content`, and that would hide that div, which would allow the background image to show...

Answer (score 0):

That's kind of the point of a **"background image"**, isn't it :P That's it's in the background, not the foreground.

Try something like this:

```
<nav>
  <img src="">
<nav>
<div class="contents">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By increasing the `top` property of the `.content` element the background image appears. So the `top` property should be the 'real' height of the image that you're using as a background, you can check it by a photo editor as the old Paint or Photoshop.

Doing such is not a good practice, since, what you are getting is how things work when you give a background image to the parent and a background color to the child, the child's background is stacked on top of the parent's. And another "issue" here is that you gave an `absolute` position to `.content` element, so this element is removed from the page flow and will be positioned relative to **NOT** its parent but to the **NEAREST PARENT** that has a `position` attribute set to a value different to the default one which is `static`, if you just remove the `position` rule then giving a `padding` equals to the heigh of the image (the background image) it would give the same. Try to avoid `absolute` positioning as long it's a necessity.

Try this:

```
.contents {
    position: absolute;
    background: blue; 
    width: 800px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 20px; 
    left: 50px; /* put the real image height here, I tried 50px and I looked fine */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.adv-signup {
  position: relative;
  background-image: linear-gradient( #fff, #eff1f1);
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 30px;
}

.contents {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 1px red;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.contents .bg {
  background: #ffffff url("https://s6.postimg.cc/ugw1p1pcx/sprite.png ") no-repeat left top;
  margin: 0;
}

.text {
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  font-weight: light;
  color: white;
  background-color: #2183c2;
}

.text h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btn {
  background: #0c5382;
}
```

```html
<div class="adv-signup">
  <div class="contents">
    <div class="bg">
      <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h3>Sign up for E-News</h3>
      <p>Leave your email and we’ll send you regular updates on programs, events and news.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <input name="adv-sign-up-email-field" id="adv-sign-up-email-field" type="text" maxlength="255" value="Enter your email" />
      <a href="#" class="btn"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have done like this

https://codepen.io/aspnetgal/pen/GBbPwp

but there shud not be`enter code here` gap between divs